# Intellij Idea - customize syntax highlighting with new keywords

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Intellij Idea to implement my project with Play-framework + Scala.
I'm also using [apidocjs](http://apidocjs.com/) to produce my API documentation.

`apidocs` uses the same syntax of `scaladoc` but with its own keywords like `@api`, `@apiDesctription`, etc.

The problem is that Intellij Idea doesn't recognize those keywords and highlights them as erroneous scaladoc tags. This is very annoying!

Is there a way to instruct Idea to accept custom keywords, avoiding this kind of issues?